Huggingface transformers eval dataset size and GPU out of memory
I have a trained BertForSequenceClassification model from huggingface transformers library, and I need to run a lot of forward passes on different data using it. I am trying to optimize batch size, which lead to strange behaviour with GPU out of memory, so that I suspect I am doing something wrong.
I use A100 with 80G memory. Here is a sketch of my code:
model = geneformer_utils.get_model(path=MODEL, output_attentions=False, enable_random_dropout=True)
training_args_dict = geneformer_utils.get_training_args(
    output_dir=OUTPUT,
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    eval_accumulation_steps=1,
)
training_args = transformers.training_args.TrainingArguments(**training_args_dict)
trainer = transformers.Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    data_collator=geneformer.DataCollatorForCellClassification(),
    train_dataset=test,
    eval_dataset=test,
    compute_metrics=None
)

data_loader = trainer.get_eval_dataloader()

full_result = []
for i in range(16):
    # 0: logits
    full_result.append([[]])
for _, batch in enumerate(data_loader):
    for i in range(16):
        gene_ids, attention_mask = batch['input_ids'], batch['attention_mask']
        model_predictions = model(
            input_ids=gene_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask,
            output_attentions=False,
            output_hidden_states=False
        )
        logits = list(model_predictions['logits'].cpu().detach().numpy())
        full_result[i][0].extend(logits)

Increasing the per_device_eval_batch_size leads to GPU out of memory, but in a strange way. When I set it to 32, several loops run successfully, but after about 4-5 loops I see the error. Inserting torch.cuda.empty_cache() prevents this error in batch size 32, or at least substantially delays it, but also seems to degrade the overall speed of the loop. However, setting the batch size to 64 runs into out of memory almost immediately. However, with 64 as the batch size this code ran successfully for a smaller dataset.
I'd like to figure out what's going on, how much memory my input data actually occupies (per one datapoint), and how to make this run more efficiently, if possible.

are you saying that changing the size of the dataset made the model run OOM? not the size of the datapoints in that dataset?

@tbrugere correct. I did a bit of investigation, it seems that huggingface Trainer moves the whole dataset to GPU first. Not 100% sure yet, but it seems likely
